# R Markdown knitr::include_url()

Tags: html, r, markdown, knitr

I am trying to include an R shiny app or a youtube video in an R Markdown report via

`knitr::include_app() or knitr::include_url()`. I have also tried with

```
<center>
<iframe src="URL" width="780px" height="610px" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
</center>
```

However, it never loads the page and only shows an empty frame. As soon as i switch to self_contained: false in the YAML, it works. However, I assume this must somehow work with a self contained HTML file no?

-> the ultimate goal would be to upload the report to rpubs

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem but instead of an empty frame, I get an error message and the html is not rendered